# Unauthorized on Web API when updating mobile app to use ROPC to request access token

Tags: authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I updated my mobile app to request an Azure AD B2C token using the ROPC policy. When I send the token as a Bearer token, same as I did with the Sign Up Sign In policy, I get an unauthorized error.

One thing I had to do was request the token via `HttpClient` because the new Microsoft.Identity.Client package does not have the `AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync()` function.

In the Web Api, I updated the `TokenValidationParameters` to have the new ROPC policy as the new `AuthenticationType` but that does not work either.

What updates do I need to make so that I can use the access token I receive back to authorize on my api?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this is set the API `ClientId` to be the same as the mobile app `ClientId` which solved the issue for me.

This seems like it is not the correct way to solve this issue, but I could not find another solution at this time.